# ConTeXt: TeX ligatures with Libertine

Tags: fonts, context

I noticed that libertine, at least as I load it, does not convert --- to –

Consider this MWE

```
\definefontfamily[libertine][rm][Linux Libertine O]
\setupbodyfont[libertine,serif]
\starttext
\input ward
\switchtobodyfont[modern,serif]
\input ward
\stoptext
```

[image: mwe after compilation]
What should I do to have --- typeset as — ?

PS: this MWE loads libertine as I expect it to do in my system, but doesn't with conTeXt live.

Comment: Cannot reproduce ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDRFw.png)).  Are you using the latest beta?

Comment: Try maybe `\definefontfamily[libertine][rm][Linux Libertine O][features=default]`

Comment: BTW, there is already a `libertine` typescript bundled with ConTeXt, so [this code](https://termbin.com/ft62) just works.

Comment: @Henri Menke. Your code solves the problem. Can you turn it into an answer? Could you btw point me where I can find bundled typescripts name? Some are listed here, https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Fonts_in_LuaTeX but libertine isn't.

Comment: You can find all typescript definitions in the `type-imp-` files in [`$TEXMFCONTEXT/tex/context/fonts/mkiv`](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/tree/beta/tex/context/fonts/mkiv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason in your installation the default font features don't seem to be passed.  This can be easily solved by passing it explicitly in the fourth argument:

```
\definefontfamily[libertine][rm][Linux Libertine O][features=default]
```